# Difference between quantile results and iqr

Tags: octave, quartile, iqr

I'm trying to understand a little more about how Octave calculates quartiles and interquartile range. Consider the following:

```
A=[1 4 7 10 14];
quantile(A, [0.25 0.75])
    ans = 3.2500   11.0000
```

This result seems consistent with [Method 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartile#Method_3) on the Wikipedia page about quartiles. Given that the interquartile range is Q3-Q1, I'd expect the result to be 7.75.

However, running `iqr(A)` gives a result of 6. Clearly this is calculated from 10 minus 4 from the original data, which is consistent with [Method 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartile#Method_2) from the same Wikipedia page.

What is the reason for using two different methods for calculating Q1 and Q3?

Comment: `help quantile` lists the methods that Octave supplies for calculating quantiles. As for `iqr()` - the documentation does not state the method.

Comment: @StephenWade That's useful to know. So it seems that `quantile` can optionally specify which method to use, but `iqr` cannot. Strange that they have different defaults though.

Comment: I had a quick look, `iqr()` calculates quantiles using `discrete_inv()` rather than the `quantile()` function. Not sure why this is. They should probably clean this up.